# Google Extension doesn't fire DOMContentLoaded, load or onload

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, domcontentloaded

I have a small project to change colour some text in any webpage. But whenever I use DOMContentLoaded, load or onload it's firing before all page loaded.

But when I use 'mousemove' listener it is working whenever I move my mouse after all page loaded.

Here is **part** of my manifest file to run my code;

```json
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["https://*.uipath.com/*"],
        "js": ["edit.js"],
        "run_at": "document_end"
    }
]
```

(Also tried run_at: document_idle, document_start but didn't work)

Here is listener part:

```
document.addEventListener("load", function(){
   // my code
})
```

I also checked readystate it is also not working, Because, page's state is turning complete before page is not loaded!

I checked readystate changing and all load listeners but it didn't work.
Also tried all run_at options in manifest file.

Comment: Why do you need to use any of those events in the first place? `"run_at": "document_end"` already means that your script will be inserted after the DOM is complete. Does your code need to wait for any additional external resources to have finished loading as well?

Comment: This site is a modern SPA, so it creates the elements asynchronously later. Use MutationObserver to detect them.